# Kafka Producer Client Python Code not working

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have my zookeeper and kafka cluster all set up and running in my localhost. I have a producer and a consumer running form the command prompt as well which runs fine. Now when I am trying out by using kafka-python library on a python script, I get the following error.

**kafka-producer.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

from kafka.errors import KafkaError

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])


try:
    future = producer.send('topic', b'From program')
    record_metadata = future.get(timeout=60)
    producer.flush()
except KafkaError as exc:
    print("Exception during getting assigned partitions - {}".format(exc))
    # Decide what to do if produce request failed...
    pass
```

**Error:**

Exception during getting assigned partitions - KafkaTimeoutError: Batch for TopicPartition(topic='topic', partition=0) containing 1 record(s) expired: 30 seconds have passed
since batch creation plus linger time

This topic exists, I have verified that.
Even my kafka-consumer.py works fine as I checked it form a producer from command prompt via
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic.

**kafka-consumer.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('topic',auto_offset_reset='earliest',group_id=None,bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
for msg in consumer:
    print (msg)
```

Comment: Sure, I edited it

Comment: Nope, that didn't help :-(

Comment: `30 seconds have passed` ... your timeout for the record is 60 seconds.

Comment: Yes, if i keep timeout to 10 seconds, it throws exception: Exception during getting assigned partitions - KafkaTimeoutError: Timeout after waiting for 10 secs.